# Python typing not working when declaring a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I'm using python 3.6, and wanted to use typing, because it's nice, you get better linting and you can catch errors before runtime, also autocomplete will be available.

I have this method :

```
def add_to_dynamic_dict(filenames_by_satustag: Dict[str, List[str]], status_tag: str, filename: str) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
```

So before calling it I created a dictionary like this :

```
filenames_by_satustag = Dict[str, List[str]]
```

But when running the script I get

> TypeError: typing.Dict[str, typing.List[str]] is not a generic class

on that line.

But it is correct according to the documentation :

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html (26.1.1 type aliases, second bloc)

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full error and a [mre] of the code raising it? I am not getting any errors from that line...

Comment: `filenames_by_satustag = Dict[str, List[str]]` does not create a dictionary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with type aliases. The method you declare expects a first argument, which you called `filenames_by_satustag` with type `Dict[str, List[str]]`. However, if I'm not mistaken, you call your method with a variable `filenames_by_satustag` which has **value** `Dict[str, List[str]]`. Hence, its type is the type of `Dict[str, List[str]]`, that is `typing._GenericAlias`. If you want to create a new type called `filenames_by_satustag`, you should do the following:

```python
filenames_by_satustag = Dict[str, List[str]]

# The function return can also be replaced by filenames_bu_satustag
def add_to_dynamic_dict(some_variable: filenames_by_satustag, status_tag: str, filename: str) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
```

If what you wanted, however, was not to create a type alias, but just to create a variable `filenames_by_satustag`, you could do it like this:

```python
filenames_by_satustag: Dict[str, List[str]] = {}
```

Comment: oooh, I get it now, what I did was say : `now you can use filenames_by_satustag as a Dict[str, List[str]] type` Thanks